# Best practice for including custom javascript in Django?

Tags: javascript, django

Still new to Django. I am trying to incorporate a calendar widget into `date` input as shown in this [tutorial](https://formden.com/blog/date-picker). The following **test.html** works fine:

```
{% extends "base_alt_simple.html" %} # note this has {% load static %}

{% block title %}Schedule{% endblock %}

{% block main_content %}

<div class="container">

  <h3>Building name</h3>

</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="bootstrap-iso">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <form method="post">
     <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label " for="date">
       Date
      </label>
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar">
        </i>
       </div>
       <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text"/>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div>
       <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit">
        Submit
       </button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
        var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
        date_input.datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            container: container,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
        })
    })
</script>
```

But, if I would like to keep the javascript in a **custom.js**, how would I load this?

Using the initial answers I use:

```
<script src="{% static 'custom.js' %}"></script>
```

But the calendar pop-out not longer works. I am clearly misunderstanding something here about how to pull in the `custom.js` functionality. Thanks for any advice.

Also, **base_alt_simple.html**:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %}</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/grayscale.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{%  static 'images/favicon.ico' %}">



    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="{% url 'index' %}">
        <img id="logo" src="{% static 'images/Logo1.png' %}">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <!-- <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> -->
      <form method='GET' action='' class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <input type='text' name='q' placeholder='Search apartments' value='{{ request.GET.q }}'/>
        <input type='submit' value='Search' />
      </form>
        <!-- <li><a href="#">User <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" id="logIcon"></span></a></li> -->
        <!-- <li><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" id="logIcon"></span></a></li> -->
      <!-- </ul> -->
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

{% block main_content %}

{% endblock %}


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="{% static 'ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js' %}"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>





</body>



</html>
```

**EDIT**
added full current **test.html**

```
{% extends "base_alt_simple.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Schedule{% endblock %}

{% block main_content %}

<div class="container">

  <h3>Building name</h3>

</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="jumbotron">
  <h4>Find a time to visit </h4>

  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">


   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <form method="post">
     <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label " for="date">
       Date
      </label>
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar">
        </i>
       </div>
       <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text"/>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div>
       <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit">
        Submit
       </button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>

  </div> <!-- row -->
  </div> <!-- /container -->

  </div> <!-- end jumbotron -->

</div> <!-- end container -->


{% endblock main_content %}


{% block scripts %}

<script src="{% static 'js/custom.js' %}"></script> 

{% endblock scripts %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use static files, follow the steps in [this django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/).

Say you placed your `yourscript.js` in your django app directory `your_app/static/yourscript.js`, all you have to do is the following:

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'yourscript.js' %}"></script>
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE:**

Make sure `custom.js` is placed *after* bootstrap and datepicker, so you could put

```
<script src="{% static 'custom.js' %}"></script>
```

right before `</body>` in `base_alt_simple.html`. Or if you don't want to put it there, you could define a scripts block:

```
{% block scripts %}

{% endblock %}
```

again right before `</body>` in `base_alt_simple.html` and in `test.html`:

```
{% load static %}
{% block scripts %}
<script src="{% static 'custom.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Also, don't forget to place `custom.js` in `your_app/static/custom.js` and to restart your server.

Comment: I have the load tag in the base template. And then I changed the script to look like yours. However, the calendar pop-out only works when I have the js script in the template. What am I not doing to pull that in through the script command?

Comment: Would it be possible to see your base_alt_simple.html?

Comment: just added full base template

Comment: just incorporated your suggestions. Now I get error: `Invalid block tag on line: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?` Updated original question to show edits.

Comment: You have to place the `{% load static %}` tag in the same file you're calling `<script src="{% static 'custom.js' %}"></script>`

Comment: Did that. I pasted the full test.html above for reference. I also added a block for scripts in the base template as the last thing before the `</body>` Still no pop-out when I click

Comment: What browser are you using? I've tried it on chrome, firefox and safari and it works. Can you make sure you restart the server? Other than that, I would need to see the browser's console log to give any further assistance.

Comment: I had a previous version of the js in my `custom.js` that was likely a problem. Cleaned it out and now works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Django loads static files into templates in quite a different way. You should first setup your `static` directory and them load your static files from there using Django's special templatetag. If you have your js code in `yourscript.js`, in your template you would do the following:

```
{% load static %}

<script src="{% static 'relative/path/from/static/dir/yourscript.js' %}"></script>
```

Django collects static files to `static` directory. In order to get more information on how to setup static directory in your project, read [the official Django doc on static files.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/)